# How can I know which URL shortener was used to shrink my links?

Tags: php, redirect, url-shortener

I want to build a website which only allows users to shorten my URLs with trusted URL shorteners (like bit.ly, goo.gl,...). How can I know which URL shortener was used to redirect visitors to my website?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reliably.

You can look at the referer (see @MehrdadEP's answer) to detect where the users are from and depending on the shortener if they followed a shortlink and possibly forbid access (until they reload the page), but you cannot stop short link services from creating short links for your site.

And often you will not see the short url at all in the referer but the page before. I do not know when this happens exactly but it seems to depend on the type of redirect used by the shortener (possibly temporary vs. permanent redirect).

And the referer gets more and more unreliably as current best-practices encourage setting [referrer policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) which prevent the browser from transmitting a referer to sites which are not in the same-origin as the link.

Answer (score 1):

use `HTTP_REFERER` header to find Referral URL. a `php` example:

```
<?php 
//method one
$ref = getenv("HTTP_REFERER"); 
echo $ref; 
//method two
print $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
?>
```

Comment: The `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is available only if his website uses HTTPS